# There is differnce in date while I convert string to date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using following code to get date from string. All seems to be good in code but while I print the output date, there is difference of 12:30 hours in date.

What may be the issue? Am I missing something ?

```
NSString *strDate = @"8/22/2017 7:00:00 AM";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:strDate];
NSLog(@"%@", [date description]);
```

**Output:**

> 2017-08-21 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: can you add this [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+0:00"]];

Comment: This is due to the timeZone difference. Which timezone is your date in? Add the same timezone during conversion to get exact time

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani If I add it, I get `2017-08-22 00:00:00`

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani Thanks, after adding `timeZone` you just told, what I need to replace "HH" with "hh" as per answer posted by @vadian.

Comment: Glad it got resolved! You're most welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hour specifier is wrong, 12 hour format is `hh`

```
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Note:

Be aware that `NSLog` prints the date always in UTC although the date formatter considers the local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

you just set the time to GMT

```
 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```